# Two filters on two tables using prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Let's suppose this is my model:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    size = models.IntegerField()
    #other fields

class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    pizza = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza, through='OrderPizza')
    #other fields


class OrderPizza(models.Model):
    update = models.BooleanField()
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I try to see within the last order the id of the pizza with size 32. **How can I do that using only one queryset?**

```
#I take the last order:
last_order =  Orders.objects.filter().order_by('-order_number')[:1]

#If we have at least one order
if last_order:
    var_last_order_id = last_order[0].id
    #First filter
    queryset_orders = Orders.objects.filter(id=var_last_order_id).prefetch_related('pizza')

    for food in queryset_orders:
        #Second filter
        pizza32 = food.pizza.filter(size = 32)
        print pizza32.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also not quite sure what part of your code you want to get rid of.
If you already retrieve the last order, you can do:

```
pizza32 = Pizza.objects.filter(order=last_order, size=32)
```

which would, of course, give you a pizza query set, so you cannot do `pizza32.id`

If you only want the pizza and do not retrieve the order beforehand, you could join the queries. This will create a query that is executed in one SQL statement:

```
pizza32 = Pizza.objects.filter(order__in=Order.objects.order_by('-order_number')[:1], size=32)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstood your requirement, but sounds like you could just do:

```
if Order.objects.exists():
    last_order = Order.objects.order_by('-order_number')[:1]
    pizza32 = last_order.pizza.filter(size=32)
```

Your loop on `queryset_orders` is unnecessary, because `last_order` is already the latest order.

Comment: I just wanted to create only one query instead of queryset_orders = Orders.objects.filter(id=var_last_order_id).prefetch_related('pizza') and pizza32 = food.pizza.filter(size = 32) do you think is that possible?

Comment: I don't think you can. What's the point of doing that in one query?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the orders where the pizza size is 32 with:

```
orders = Orders.objects.filter(pizza__size=32)
```

You can get the last of these orders with:

```
last_order = Orders.objects.filter(
    pizza__size=32,
).order_by('-order_number')[0]
```

Using `prefetch_related`, you can fetch the pizzas in the same query:

```
last_order = Orders.objects.filter(
    pizza__size=32,
).order_by('-order_number').prefetch_related('pizza')[0]
```

Now, when you do `last_order.pizza.all()`, there won't be any additional SQL queries. If you know there was only one pizza in the order, you can do:

```
for pizza in last_order.pizza.all():
    pizza
```

Or to get the first pizza from the order:

```
last_order.pizza.all()[0]
```